# Run sync adapter when Calendar Provider updates

Tags: android, calendar, android-syncadapter, dataprovider

I can be notified of changes to my own data providers by registering a `ContentObserver` using `registerContentObserver()` on my Activity.

Presumably this only captures requests to URIs that I implement.

Is there a way to register for changes on content providers implemented by other authorities e.g. Calendar Provider?

I want to run my `SyncAdapter` every time the phone calendar is updated to synchronise my own database with the calendar's database.

Comment: There might still be an answer - you could try registering a `ContentObserver` on calendar URIs since I don't think I fully explored that route. In the end I just periodically synced the Calendar since it met my needs for a demo prototype.